# Drupal integration with another Drupal DB?

Tags: drupal, integration

I have two Drupal sites. Let's call them Site A and Site B.

Site A is a site where users can post ITEMS. So I have a content type called ITEM. Site B is a client's site. I want to be able to display the ITEMS from Site A on Site B. I don't want to have to import the content. Both sites are on the same server. I want the items that show on Site B to be the exact items from Site A. In fact, it would be amazing if:

1. The items show in the content list
2. The user can edit content from Site A via Site B.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a module that can do this?
2. If not, is this a feasible way to go about it and should I start development myself?
3. Is importing and exporting the only route to go? (and then disabling the editing of those content types)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should use [domain](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module. I have only used it with subdomains, but it should be able to handle different tld as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use feedapi and feedapi mapper to sync nodes on site A and site B.